# Adding timestamp to output with AWK

Tags: bash, awk, grep

```
while [ ! -f /home/stopPing.txt ] ; do 
cat /home/ipListforPing.txt |  while read output
do
    timestamp=$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S)
    timeout 2s ping -qc1 $output 2>&1 | awk -F/ '/^rtt/ { printf "OK %.2f ms\n", $5; ok = 1 } END { if (!ok) print "FAIL" }' >> $output.txt
#echo "----------------"
done
sleep 1.85;
done
```

Hello, how can I add a timestamp variabl to this output.
wherever I type the timestamp variable I get an error.
This is the output I want to see,

```
19-01-2021_03-11-48 OK 0.02 ms
```

Comment: What does _I get an error_ mean?

Comment: Please, show the sample data with related expected output, do not post them as images or comments. Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: The output from the above command is this: `OK 0.02 ms`

I want to add a timestamp to it beging of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the timestamp within awk using the strftime function (GNU awk) without the need to use date outside:

```
timeout 2s ping -qc1 $output 2>&1 | awk -F/ '/^rtt/ { printf strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S")" OK %.2f ms\n", $5; ok = 1 } END { if (!ok) print "FAIL" }' >> $output.txt
```

Without GNU awk:

```
timeout 2s ping -qc1 $output 2>&1 | awk -v timestamp="$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S)" -F/ '/^rtt/ { printf timestamp" OK %.2f ms\n", $5; ok = 1 } END { if (!ok) print "FAIL" }' >> $output.txt
```

Pass the result of the date command into awk with -v as a variable timestamp.

Comment: I try it but output :`awk: line 2: function strftime never defined'`

Comment: Apologies, this is only available on GNU awk.

Comment: I've added a none GNU solution

Comment: If it meets your requirements. Please, kindly accept it as an answer